# NSLayoutConstraint won't work

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint

I want to move 2 button to center of width of screen.
It's should looks like: |<-(100)FirstButton(50)->SecondButton(100)->|

I started from first button.

```
var const = NSLayoutConstraint(item: firstButton, 
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 
    relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 
    toItem: view.superview, 
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 
    multiplier: 1.0, 
    constant: 100)
```

Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Could it be that you have not added any constraint for the vertical position. The one you have added is only for horizontal.

Comment: I did. I made constraint in IB for horizontal and vertical

Comment: Where I can read about VFL in Swift?

Comment: Did you actually add the constraint to the superview (or set the constraint to enabled, if targeting 10.10)?

Comment: First of all, it's for iOS. Second I tried several options. 1. Add constraints to IB and just edit. 2. Modify exist constraints. But all time I get or runtime error or it's just not work. I really want to see some examples how to use VFL. Step by step. Any info?

Comment: To be sure, do you have add `self.view.addConstraint(const);`

Comment: Yes, I did. I go another way: just added constraints in IB and JUST modify in code (not create). But I still need good examples about constraints and VFL in Swift :(

Comment: in IB do you have set placeholder constraints?

Comment: No. It was default. Can you explain for what it is need?

Comment: You can look here http://natashatherobot.com/ios-auto-layout-tips-tricks/ and here http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/ hope it will help to understand

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try to learn it even it's for xcode 5 and obj-c

Answer (score 1):

It seem that `firstButton` have not set the property `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`

**Apple document description of `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`:**

`/* By default, the autoresizing mask on a view gives rise to constraints that fully determine 
     the view's position. This allows the auto layout system to track the frames of views whose 
     layout is controlled manually (through -setFrame:, for example).
     When you elect to position the view using auto layout by adding your own constraints, 
     you must set this property to NO. IB will do this for you.
     */
    @available(iOS 6.0, *)
    open var translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: Bool // Default YES`

So you must set `firstButton`'s `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false when you adding your own constraints